Need help on ASP.NET, <asp:Label> validation
Whenever I make validation and assign the control to validation using ContorlToValidate.
But whenever the asp:label is connected to validation it still gives out this uncaught error.
"Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Control 'labelID' referenced by the ControlToValidate property of 'validatorID' cannot be validated."
I have used CustomValidator, RegexValidator and requiredValidator.
the code goes like this.
`
<asp:GridView ......attributes...... 
     <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
               <ItemPemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:Label ID="labelIDn" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("text") %>'
                                   CssClass="txtSmall"></asp:Label>
                        <asp:CustomValidator ID="validatorID"
                                             ClientValidationFunction="labelValidator"
                                             ErrorMessage="validation failed" 
                                             ControlToValidate="labelID" 
                                             Display="Dynamic" runat="server" />
                   </div>
                 </ItemTemplate>
      <Columns>
<asp:GridView>

there was more content in the gridview and I wrote down where I am trying validation.
I have tried onservervalidate too
and this is the validator for ClientValidationFunction
function Validator(sender, args) {

    var val = args.value.toString();
    if (val == null) {
        args.IsValid = false;
    } else {
        var isInt = /^-?[0-9]*$/.test(args.value);
        if (isInt) {
            args.IsValid = true;
        } else {
            args.IsValid = false;
        }
    }
}

and when I try onserviervalidate, it still shares same loging but in c#
Tried different type of validation

Why would you want to validate a label??? A user cannot enter data into it!

@VDWWD I know it sounds not very useful but I have to fix what the security program says if something is vulnerable. And it say it is vulnerable to CSS attack. so I am figuring out now..

As noted, it makes no sense to try and validate a label this way. And double worse is you placing the label in a GridView, and such validation will not trigger at render time anyway.
Validators are for input controls only, and they ONLY fire when the USER changes that control in question.
If you looking to format, or change, or allow, or not allow a given value for that label in a GridView, then you can (and should) use the GridView on row data bound, and test the value at that point, and then format the value as you wish. As such, a validator does not apply to such a use case.
Place your code in the GridView's row data bound event.
So, say this markup for the GridView:
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
    CssClass="table table-hover" Width="50%"                
    OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound"  >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblActive" runat="server" Text="">
                </asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>

And code to load, and code to test/check/change/reformat/modify the label to whatever we want using the Row Data Bound event (runs for each row of the GridView) is this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL =
            "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName";

        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRst(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();   
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DataRowView gData = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
            Label lblActive = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("lblActive");

            if ((gData["Active"] == null) || ((bool)gData["Active"] == false))
                lblActive.Text = "Not Active";
            else
                lblActive.Text = "Active Hotel";
        }
    }

And the result is this:

So, to change, or test, or modify, or verify the contents of that label in the GridView, as above shows, we are able to re-format, or use code to place any value we want into that label based on the data for each row of the GridView.
So, in above, I check if the Active column (a SQL server bit column) is null, or false, or is true, and the code thus takes appropriate action to format the label any way I want. Keep in mind that the DataItem used to bind the GridView row is only valid during the data binding process, and once data binding has completed, the DataItem goes out of scope.
